# Validating a String Input

Tags: java

How would I validate this string input in Java?

> Two letter followed by three digits and a letter. The last letter can only be B for Business Account or N for Non-Business Account

An example of this would be 'JB213B' or 'JB231N'.

EDIT: Right, I'm now using a regular expression, thank you.

Though now I pose how to actually carry out the validation, here is what I have so far

```
            System.out.println("Enter your reference");
            String reference = keyboard.next();
            String regex = "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[B|N]";
            boolean match = reference.matches(regex);
            while (!match)
            {
                System.out.println("That isn't a valid reference");
                reference = keyboard.next();
                match = reference.matches(regex);
            }
```

Comment: Iterate through each character of the string and make sure it's what it's supposed to be? Alternatively, perhaps a regex would work.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a less-infuriating way rather than iterating through each character, but thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason why using a regex wouldn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Just to be sure someone fights for the non-regex possibilities:

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    return s.length() == 6 &&
        s.charAt(0) >= 'A' && s.charAt(0) <= 'Z' &&
        s.charAt(1) >= 'A' && s.charAt(1) <= 'Z' &&
        s.charAt(2) >= '0' && s.charAt(2) <= '9' &&
        s.charAt(3) >= '0' && s.charAt(3) <= '9' &&
        s.charAt(4) >= '0' && s.charAt(4) <= '9' &&
        (s.charAt(5) == 'B' || s.charAt(5) == 'N');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compare the string to a regex using the matches() method.

```
// Match A-Z twice, 0-9 three times, and B or N once
String myString = "JB213B";
String myPattern = "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[BN]{1}";
if(myString.matches(myPattern){
    // Do continuing logic
} else {
    // Do error logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using regular expressions.

In this case the expression would be `^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[B|N]$`

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) is a reference for `.matches()` method of `String` class.

Likewise, you can also use `Pattern` class to find matches. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is a reference for that.

**Usage:**

```
    String strToTest = "AB123B";
    String pattern = "^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[B|N]$";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(strToTest);
    boolean b = m.matches();
```

**Performance Comparison:**

Which is better "Using Regex" or "Using String Comparisons"?

This question is always debatable. But I find, understanding the complexity of requirement is little helpful in every case.

If there are many string comparisons required which could be skipped by use of regexes then I would go with regexes.

But one should also consider that using multiple and/or complex regexes will have its impact on the performance, as the evaluation of a regex is a tedious and complex process for compilers as well (when compared to string operations).

On the other hand, use of String comparisons is also prone to errors as we directly deal with indices and stripping off of unnecessary parts.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of a regular expression like the following.

```
String st = "JB213B";
String regex= "[A-Z]{2}\\d{3}[BN]";

boolean match = st.matches(regex);
```

Comment: So, would this work to validate the input?


`System.out.println("Enter your reference");
                String reference = keyboard.next();
                String regex = "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[B|N]";
                boolean match = reference.matches(regex);
                while (match = false)
                {
                    System.out.println("That isn't a valid reference");
                    reference = keyboard.next();
                    match = reference.matches(regex);
                }`

Comment: Yes that looks right, except it is (match == false), not (match = false), better yet, write _(!match)_ instead .I have just edited your post to change that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I can stop ripping my hair out over something as silly as this :')